# Chatbot sending message from user in Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm currently trying to develop a chat bot for my Facebook page. The main idea is that a user tells the chat bot which of his/her friend he would like to send a message. The user then proceeds to select an image and an appropriate text to go along with this image.

After this the chat bot is supposed to send this message to the chosen recipient. I have however not been able to find anything about this issue in the documentation, which got me wondering whether or not this is possible.

Is it at all possible to request permission to send a message from a users profile? If not, are there any ways to making this less of a hassle to the user, as I would prefer this could be automated in some way.

Any inputs and ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on messenger. In order to get a user's page-scoped ID, which I needed to target the message, the user must opt-in to a chat with your page/bot. Some of the ways the opt in can occur include sending a message to your bot, hitting the get started button in the welcome screen, and entering through one of the web plugins.

There is no way to send a message on a user's behalf or to spoof the user.